# How to get from nested JSON by int rather then by name in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb, postgresql, mysql-8.0

So I'm currently using MySQL's JSON field to store some data.

So the 'reports' table looks like this:

```
id | stock_id | type             | doc                          |
1  | 5        | Income_Statement | https://pastebin.com/bj1hdK0S|
```

The pastebin is the content of the json field

What I want to do is get a number (ebit) from the first object under yearly (2018-12-31) in the JSON and then use that to do a WHERE query on so that it only returns where ebit > 50000000 for example. The issue is that the dates under yearly are not standard (i.e. one might be 2018-12-31, the other might by 2018-12-15). So essentially I want a way to get the data using integer indexes rather than the actual names of the objects, so something like yearly.[0].ebit.

How would I do this in MySQL? Alternatively if it's not possible in MySQL, would it be possible in either PostgeSQL or Mongo? If so, could you give me an example? Most of the data fits well into MySQL only this table has a JSON column which is why I started with MySQL.

so StackOverflow isn't letting my link to pastebin without some code so here's some random code:

```
if(dog == "poodle") {
    print "test"
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using MySQL 8. Alternatively would the new XDevAPI (MySQL's document store) make this easier?

Comment: I would just write an import script to load the records into a normal table. You're pounding a square peg into a round hole by trying to use SQL to query the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for MySQL nor MongoDB, but here's a simple version for PostgreSQL JSONB type:

```sql
SELECT (doc->'yearly'-> max(years) -> 'ebit')::numeric AS ebit
FROM reports, jsonb_object_keys(doc->'yearly') AS years
GROUP BY reports.doc;
```

...with simplistic test data:

```sql
WITH reports(doc) AS (
    SELECT '{"yearly":{"2018-12-31":{"ebit":123},"2017-12-31":{"ebit":1.23}}}'::jsonb
)
SELECT (doc->'yearly'-> max(years) -> 'ebit')::numeric AS ebit
FROM reports, jsonb_object_keys(doc->'yearly') AS years
GROUP BY reports.doc;
```

...gives:

```
 ebit 
------
  123
(1 row)
```

So I've basically selected the *latest* entry under `"yearly"` without knowing actual values but assuming that the key date formatting will allow a sort order (in this case it seems to comply with ISO-8601).

Using data type `JSON` instead of `JSONB` would preserve object key order but is not as efficient in PostgreSQL further down the road and wouldn't help here either.

IF you want to then select only those `reports` entries having their latest `ebit` greater than a certain value, just pack it into a sub-select or a CTE. I usualy prefer CTE's because they are better to read, so here we go:

```sql
WITH
    reports (id, doc) AS (
        VALUES
        (1, '{"yearly":{"2018-12-31":{"ebit":123},"2017-12-31":{"ebit":1.23}}}'::jsonb),
        (2, '{"yearly":{"2018-12-23":{"ebit":50},"2017-12-22":{"ebit":"1200.00"}}}'::jsonb)
    ),
    r_ebit (id, ebit) AS (
        SELECT reports.id, (reports.doc->'yearly'-> max(years) -> 'ebit')::numeric AS ebit
        FROM reports, jsonb_object_keys(doc->'yearly') AS years
        GROUP BY reports.id, reports.doc
    )
SELECT id, ebit
FROM r_ebit
WHERE ebit > 100;
```

However, as you already see, it is not possible to filter the original rows using this strategy. A pre-processing step would make sense here so that the JSON format actually is filter-friendly.

**ADDENDUM**

To add the possibility of selecting the values for the *n*-th completed fiscal year, we need resort to window functions and we also need to reduce the resulting set to only return a single row per actual group (in the demonstration case: `reports.id`):

```sql
WITH reports(id, doc) AS (VALUES
    (1, '{"yearly":{"2018-12-31":{"ebit":123},"2017-12-31":{"ebit":1.23},"2016-12-31":{"ebit":"23.42"}}}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{"yearly":{"2018-12-23":{"ebit":50},"2017-12-22":{"ebit":"1200.00"}}}'::jsonb)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) reports.id, (reports.doc->'yearly'-> (lead(years, 0) over (partition by reports.doc order by years desc nulls last)) ->>'ebit')::numeric AS ebit
FROM reports, jsonb_object_keys(doc->'yearly') AS years
GROUP BY 1, reports.doc, years.years ORDER BY 1;
```

...will behave exactly as using the `max` aggregate function previously. Increasing the offset parameter within the `lead(years, <offset>)` function all will select the *n*-th year backwards (because of descending order of the window partition).

The `DISTINCT ON (1)` clause is the magic that reduces the result to a single row per distinct column value (first column = `reports.id`). This is why the `NULLS LAST` is very important inside the window `OVER` clause.

Here are results for different offsets (I've added a third historic entry for the first `id` but not for the second to also show how it deals with absent entries):

**N = 0**:

```
 id | ebit 
----+------
  1 |  123
  2 |   50
```

**N = 1**

```
 id |  ebit   
----+---------
  1 |    1.23
  2 | 1200.00
```

**N = 2**

```
 id | ebit  
----+-------
  1 | 23.42
  2 |
```

...which means absent entries will just result in a `NULL` value.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a function that could get the second (or any) highest year, like max(years, 1)?

Comment: Added the _N_-th top value version.